# How to deploy from Github Actions to Digital Ocean Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

Github repo: https://github.com/jonesrussell/portfolio-sapper

Here is my Github Action YML:

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  export-docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: jonesrussell/portfolio-app:latest
      - name: Image digest
        run: echo ${{ steps.docker_build.outputs.digest }}
      - name: DigitalOcean Kubernetes
        uses: matootie/dokube@v1.3.4
        with:
          personalAccessToken: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN }}
          clusterName: galaxy-k8s
```

What I can't figure out is how to: kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yml with matootie/dokube@v1.3.4

Cheers

Comment: Did you check this? https://www.digitalocean.com/blog/how-to-deploy-to-digitalocean-kubernetes-with-github-actions/

Answer (score 1):

What `matootie/dokube` does is it configures `kubectl` and adds it to the runner path. After you use it in your workflows you can add any additional steps using the `kubectl` executable as you would anything else, just as I have added to your original workflow file:

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  export-docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...

      - name: Apply changes
        run: kubectl apply -f kubernetes.yml
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the repository.

Comment: Nice to post formatted code and useful answer. Use the Answer section for code and explanation related to the question. Use comments to elaborate on your credentials and to offer moral support :)